# Grouping sets algorithm

Tags: algorithm, set, grouping

Need to develop an algorithm to solve the following task

Given:

```
The N sets with a different number of elements
```

Expected Result:

```
The new M sets containing ≥X common elements of the N sets
```

Example:

```
N1=[1,2,3,4,5]
N2=[2,3,5]
N3=[1,3,5]
N4=[1,2]

if X=3:

M1=[1] (from N1,3,4)
M2=[2] (from N1,2,4)
M3=[3,5] (from N1,2,3)
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941781/algorithm-to-find-common-subsets

Comment: Off the top of my head: sort the elements of the input sets.  then use merge-match to progress through each extant integer, counting each one as you go.  Those with Count >= X go in an M set.  Use binary encoding on N set member ship for each such integer, to make a hash to group members into the M sets.

Comment: are the new M sets disjoint, or not?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37184048/find-all-subsets-from-list-of-sets-that-appears-in-at-least-n-different-sets

Answer (score 1):

Given N sets (noted `Ni`) of **sorted** integers, initialize N variables`Hi`which will hold the heads of each set.

While there still exist indexes`Hi`that haven't reached the end of their respective`Ni`, iterate over the values`Vi=Ni[Hi]`and find the minimum value`Vmin`, count the number of occurrences`n`and store the corresponding indexes`j`(which you can all do in one loop).

Increment the`Hj`.

If`n>X`, this gives you a new set`M = [Vmin] (from Nj)`.

Up to you to model the data representation accordingly so as to use`(from Nj)`as a map key.