# Find all subsets from list of sets that appears in at least N different sets

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm working on algorithm of grouping keywords from search engine by amount of same urls they have in SERP. Each group represents an url, and each value is an id of keyword for SERP where url appeared.

---

I have list of groups:

```
groups = [
    [1],
    [1, 2 ,3],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [1, 2, 3 ,4], 
    [2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [4, 5, 7]
]
```

I need to fetch **ALL** sets of items that appears at least in N groups in order of "size" decreases:

In example above for N=3 we have two subsets:
[1, 2 ,3] and [4, 5]

---

As i see how to fetch it:

**Iteration 1:** find largest set that appears at least 3 times (it's [1, 2 ,3]) and delete from all set, where it appears.

After iteration we have:

```
groups = [
        [1],
        [4, 5],
        [4], 
        [2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [4, 5, 7]
    ]
```

**Iteration 2:** find largest that appears at least 3 times (it's [4, 5])

After iteration we have:

```
groups = [
        [1],
        [4], 
        [2, 3],
        [6],
        [7]
    ]
```

**End of algorithm**: because there is no more sets that appears at least 3 times in groups.

---

Do you have any idea for algorithm to fetch them?

**N** is between 1 and 10.

p.s. groups list is quite big, from 1000 to 10000 items. Numbers is ids of objects in db.

Comment: Why is [1, 2, 3] a group but not [1], [1, 2] or [1, 2, 3, 4] ?

Comment: Badly phrased. It is not clear what the problem is. Define the group-constraint more precise. While i think i got the idea, it would help a lot.

Comment: @mcmlxxxvi, take a look on question once more.

Comment: @sascha, take a look on question once more.

Comment: Seriously... Your current edits make the description worse. I can give you a simple algorithm which is compatible with what you describe, but it won't really solve your problem, because i don't know what exactly is your problem. What do you mean by excluding largest subset? And when you say subsets of items: [1] is a subset of an item and appears >=N times.

Comment: Why is `[4, 5]` a group while `[2, 3]` isn't?

Comment: @sascha, sry. English isn't my native language as you can see.. :) I've added some corrections. Now I hope it'll be clear.

Comment: Sorry, but a set of your items (e.g. item [4,5,6]) always contain many "complete" items (e.g set = {[1], [1,2,3]}). In this case your solution [4,5] is not possible as its not an item. And you probably want ONE set as solution. It would help if you stick to mathematical terms (e.g. basic set-theory)

Comment: @YuryTarabanko, because resulting sets should be as large as possible.

Comment: @Paul Because only one item contains all five numbers (we need N>=3 items). But yeah, the description is still lacking some consistence.

Comment: @sascha, I've added explanation on how I see algorithm execution flow.

Comment: @AlexT the definition still isn't complete. Or some parts of the solution are incorrect. I've tried to make a bit more clear what you want - or at least the part that I get

Comment: @Alex T There are still problems with the description. The set {1,2,3} appears only one time. The two you are counting extra are supersets of this one. Please read about set-theory and get a grasp of the notations/terms.

Comment: @Paul, added fix for question. "I need to fetch **ALL** sets of items that appears at least in N groups in order of "size" decreases"

Comment: @AlexT What do you do if the largest subset isn't unique? Also -- what language are you trying to implement in? It makes a huge difference if you are using a language with built-in support for sets.

Comment: @JohnColeman, python. What do you mean under "isn't unique"?

Comment: @AlexT that at least makes the approach clearer. But it's still lacking some determinism. E.g. what if Iteration 1 winds up with 2 sets, that are distinct, have same size and items both appear same number of times?

Comment: @sascha, it only meters that elements 1,2,3 appears in three groups.

Comment: @Alex T I got it. But it is not described as that. And what is the range of your values (min/max)?

Comment: @I mean what if e.g. *both* `{1,2,3}` and `{4,5,6}` occur `N` times? Do you select *both* subsets and remove the elements of *both*?. Also -- if you are using Python I would *start* by running the data through a comprehension. If your current list is called `groups` do something like `groups = [set(group) for group in groups]` to convert to a list of sets, and then look into `itertools` to find methods to iterate through collections of `N` sets.

Comment: @Paul, then we can fetch them all on the same iteration.

Comment: @sascha, min=0 max=MaxInt, its db PKs.

Comment: "delete from all set" That would be incorrect. Replace `[2,3]` with `[2,3,4]` and watch how `[2,3,4]` that appears 3 times can't be found once you delete `[1,2,3]` from all sets.

Comment: What is the intended size of `N`? If it is relatively small a somewhat naïve approach should be possible. But if it gets much larger than 3, the number of potential collections of `N` items (drawn for a list with up to 10000 elements) becomes infeasibly large.

Comment: @JohnColeman, N is between 1 and 10.

Comment: Can groups appear more than once? Are you really dealing with a *set* of groups or is it a *multiset* of groups?

Comment: @n.m., we need to group values together. In your example there will be groups [1,2,3], [4,5].

Comment: @JohnColeman, yes, there is not restriction for groups = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]. Now I'm working with 'list' of 'set' in python. And probably correct way to name it as multiset of groups because groups can have same sets of values.

Comment: @JohnColeman, "... itertools to find methods to iterate through collections of N sets" I can't understand that part, how this can help me?

Comment: Well, with a list of  up to 10000 sets and `N` as high as 10, my itertools idea is probably dead in the water. The binomial coefficient `C(10000,10)` is roughly 2.7 x 10**33. The brute-force approach of intersecting all collections of 10 groups won't work out. How large is the *union* of all groups? (in your example, it has 7 items). If this number is small compared to the number of groups (as would be the case if there is a lot of repetitions) if have some ideas that could work.

Comment: Is `[2,3,4]` not a group? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an `itertools` approach for the first part of what you call `Iteration 1`. If it is feasible to run it at all, then you can run it repeatedly in a loop, removing the found items at each stage. As I indicated in the comments, it is only feasible for small `n`:

```
import itertools

def intersect(sets):
    #forms the intersection of all s in sets
    #assumes that there is at least one

    I = sets[0].copy()
    for s in sets[1:]:
        I = I & s
    return I

def largestIntersection(sets,n):
    maxSize = 0
    maxSets = [set()]
    for groupCombo in itertools.combinations(sets,n):
        I = intersect(groupCombo)
        if len(I) > maxSize:
            maxSize = len(I)
            maxSets = [I]
        elif len(I) == maxSize:
            maxSets.append(I)
    return maxSets
```

For example:

```
>>> groups = [
    [1],
    [1, 2 ,3],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [1, 2, 3 ,4],
    [2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [4, 5, 7]
]
>>> groups = [set(group) for group in groups]
>>> largestIntersection(groups,3)
[{1, 2, 3}]
```

**On Edit:** The following modification *might* help -- depending on distribution of numbers in the groups and the size of the groups:

```
def guessSize(sets,n,trials):
    return max(len(intersect(random.sample(sets,n))) for trial in range(trials))

def maxIntersection(sets,n,trials = 100000):
    k = guessSize(sets,n,trials)
    filteredSets = [s for s in sets if len(s) >= k]
    return largestIntersection(filteredSets,n)
```

The idea is to first reduce the number of groups before you try to iterate over the intersections. For example:

```
#stress test:

import random
nums = list(range(1,101))
testGroups = [set(random.sample(nums,random.randint(1,100))) for n in range(1000)]
foundGroups = maxIntersection(testGroups,3)
```

it takes only a few seconds to compute `foundGroups` as opposed to several minutes if I had directly used `largestIntersection(testGroups)`. On the other hand, with different choices of the random parameters the time saving becomes negligible.

**On Further Edit:** Perhaps you can be even more aggressive with the filtering:

```
import collections
def maxIntersection(sets,n,trials = 100000):
    k = guessSize(sets,n,trials)
    filteredSets = [s for s in sets if len(s) >= k]
    counts = collections.Counter()
    for s in filteredSets:
        for x in s:
            counts[x] +=1
    t = {x for x,c in counts.items() if c >= k}
    filteredSets = [s & t for s in filteredSets if len(s & t) >= k]
    return largestIntersection(filteredSets,n)
```

Comment: It works, but really slow.. it was bad idea to work with sets. Thanks.

Comment: It has nothing to do with sets as data-structure itself. It's about the combinations which we need to try.

Comment: @sascha, of course it is. I mean approach of solving the problem in general.

Comment: @AlexT It does seem to be an algorithmically difficult problem. See if the optimization in the edit helps.

Answer (score 1):

A first prototype approach/hack combining the beauty of recursion, pseudo-functional programming and ***-up stuff from my side. There are a lot of improvements possible, especially regarding iterators/lists. Maybe this even qualifies as spaghetti-code :-).

*Warning: see comment of @John Coleman regarding binomial coefficient. We are generating all possible subsets of remaining values in each iteration. It might be improved if generators are used lazily (but will still be infeasible for huge sets of unique numbers).*

```
import itertools

groups = [
    [1],
    [1, 2 ,3],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [1, 2, 3 ,4],
    [2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [4, 5, 7]
]

def solve(groups, N, sol=[]):
    if len(groups) == 0:
        return sol

    rem_vals = list(set(itertools.chain(*groups)))
    combs = list(itertools.product(range(2), repeat=len(rem_vals)))
    combs_ = [[rem_vals[ind] for ind, i in enumerate(combs[comb]) if i] for comb in range(len(combs))]

    for cand in reversed(sorted(combs_, key=lambda x: len(list(itertools.chain(x))))):
        if len(cand) == 0:
            continue
        else:
            counter = 0
            inds = []
            for ind, g in enumerate(groups):
                if set(cand).issubset(g):
                    counter += 1
                    inds.append(ind)

            if counter >= N:
                sol.append(cand)
                for i in inds:
                    for j in cand:
                        groups[i].remove(j)
                return solve(groups, N, sol)

    return sol

print(solve(groups, 3))
```

Output

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]
```

Comment: For 200 phrases and 1880 links (i.e. len(groups) ) program memory usage in 10 sec  exceeded 12gb, so I can't your soltion on real data :)

Comment: I think someone asked for the unique number of vals in your sets and you did not respond. Of yourse it won't work if this set is big. The same for John Coleman's solution. You could make lists to generators to improve memory, but performance regarding time will not change.

Comment: John Coleman's solution works, but it takes few minutes to get results. I will search for another way to solve this problem..

Comment: I indicated the difference of the approaches. Its just a few modifications. One uses more memory and is faster, the other one is slower but needs less memory. You choose.

Comment: Sry, I missed question about unique values. For 1880 sets there is 180 unique values. Something like that.